Problem with music21: it ignores musical rests
I have a code which reads notes (beginning_time, pitch, duration) from one track of a midi and write these notes to another midi, but the original midi contains rests, at the end those rests don't appear in the exit midi. Does somebody know why Music21 ignores the rests? Thanks every one by your comments.
from music21 import *
import math
from music21 import stream, note, tempo

ruta_archivo_seleccionado = 'Original.mid'

print("\nLeyendo el MIDI")
#Cargar el archivo MIDI*
mf = converter.parse(ruta_archivo_seleccionado)

#Obtener el primer track*
t = mf.parts[0]

#Listas y Diccionarios
notas = []#Crear una lista para almacenar las notas con su altura, momento de inicio, duración y compás*
notas_por_compas = {}#Crear una lista o diccionario para almacenar las notas con su altura, momento de inicio, duración y compás*
melodia_padre = {}#Crear una lista o diccionario para almacenar las notas con su altura, momento de inicio, duración y compás*


#Iterar sobre las notas del track*
#tiempo_actual = 0
h = 0
#print("\nLista Notas:")
#print("      [nota compas tiempo altura nombre  duración]")

print("Extrayendo las notas y calculando las entropias\n")
for n in t.flatten().notes:
    altura_numerica = n.pitches[0].midi  # Altura de la nota en formato numérico (midi)
    altura_literal = n.pitches[0].nameWithOctave  # Altura de la nota en formato literal (do, re, etc.)
    momento_inicio = round(float(n.offset),2)
    #tick_inicio = int(n.offset * mf.ticksPerQuarter)
    duracion = round(float(n.duration.quarterLength),2)
    compas = n.measureNumber  # Compás donde está ubicada la nota
    notas.append({'altura_numerica': altura_numerica, 'altura_literal': altura_literal, 'inicio': momento_inicio, 'duracion': duracion, 'compas': compas})
    #print(compas, momento_inicio, altura_numerica, altura_literal, duracion )
    #print(f"Nota: {h:<3} {beat_evento:<7}    {altura:<3}     {duracion}      {compas_evento:<6} {beat_evento}") #ESTA
    print("Nota compas t_inicio alt_numerica alt_literal duracion")
    print(f" {h:<5} {compas:<5}  {momento_inicio:<8}   {altura_numerica:<11}  {altura_literal:<6}    {duracion} ")
    h = h + 1
    #Pasa la información al diccionario notas_por_compas
    if compas not in notas_por_compas:
        notas_por_compas[compas] = {'alturas': [], 'duraciones': []} # Solo esta linea debe ir dentro del if
    notas_por_compas[compas]['alturas'].append(altura_literal) # En cambio estas lineas van dentro del for
    notas_por_compas[compas]['duraciones'].append(duracion)
        #Cuenta de duraciones diferentes
    notas_por_compas[compas]['cuenta_alturas_diferentes'] = len(set(notas_por_compas[compas]['alturas']))
        #Cuenta de duraciones diferentes
    notas_por_compas[compas]['cuenta_duraciones_diferentes'] = len(set(notas_por_compas[compas]['duraciones']))
        #Total de elementos en el compas
    notas_por_compas[compas]['total_elementos'] = len(notas_por_compas[compas]['alturas'])
    if compas not in melodia_padre:
        melodia_padre[compas] = []
    melodia_padre[compas].append({'t_inicio': momento_inicio, 'altura': altura_numerica, 'duracion': duracion})

melodia_hijo = {}

for compas, notas in melodia_padre.items():
    melodia_hijo[compas] = []
    for nota in notas:
        nueva_altura = nota['altura'] + 0  # Sumar 2 a la altura_numerica
        melodia_hijo[compas].append({'t_inicio': nota['t_inicio'], 'altura': nueva_altura, 'duracion': nota['duracion']})

nuevo_midi = stream.Stream()

nuevo_tempo = tempo.MetronomeMark(number=100)  # Reemplaza 120 con el valor de tempo deseado

nuevo_midi.insert(0, nuevo_tempo)

for compas, notas in melodia_hijo.items():
    for nota in notas:
        if nota['altura'] is not None:
            nueva_nota = note.Note()
            nueva_nota.pitch.midi = nota['altura']  # Establecer la altura de la nota
            nueva_nota.offset = nota['t_inicio']  # Establecer el momento de inicio de la nota
            nueva_nota.duration.quarterLength = nota['duracion']  # Establecer la duración de la nota
            print("Valores de nueva_nota:", compas, nueva_nota.pitch.midi, nueva_nota.offset, nueva_nota.duration.quarterLength)  # Instrucción print para monitorear los valores
            nuevo_midi.append(nueva_nota)
            
nuevo_midi.write('midi', 'hijo.mid')



There are no rests in a MIDI file.  There's just "note on" and "note off", and when the notes are off, nothing sounds.  You have to manage the timestamps to get the timing right.

Yes Tim, but I believe that music21 must consider it in statement: nueva_nota.offset = nota['t_inicio']  # Establecer el momento de inicio de la nota

You're referring to nota['t_inicio'], but your notas array does not contain 't_inicio'.  It contains 'inicio'.  Nor does it contain 'altura'.

Yes they are, I print them at the begining with: print(f" {h:<5} {compas:<5}  {momento_inicio:<8}   {altura_numerica:<11}  {altura_literal:<6}    {duracion} ") and at the exit with print("Valores de nueva_nota:", compas, nueva_nota.pitch.midi, nueva_nota.offset, nueva_nota.duration.quarterLength)  # Instrucción print para monitorear los valores

There are a couple of problems here, all related to the time signature.  You are collecting the measure numbers (in compas), but you are not gathering the output into measures.  And, more importantly, you are not declaring a time signature, so when you put three quarter notes into a measure, it assumes the measure is full, and you don't need any rests.
I changed the last part of your script to this, and it works for me:
nuevo_midi = stream.Stream()
nuevo_midi.insert(0, tempo.MetronomeMark(number=140) )
nuevo_midi.insert(0, meter.TimeSignature('4/4'))

for compas, notas in melodia_hijo.items():
    measure = stream.Measure()
    for nota in notas:
        if nota['altura']:
            nueva_nota = note.Note()
            nueva_nota.pitch.midi = nota['altura']
            nueva_nota.offset = nota['t_inicio']
            nueva_nota.duration.quarterLength = nota['duracion'] 
            print("Valores de nueva_nota:", compas, nueva_nota.pitch.midi, nueva_nota.offset, nueva_nota.duration.quarterLength)
            measure.append(nueva_nota)
    nuevo_midi.append( measure )
nuevo_midi.show()
            
for n in nuevo_midi.flatten().notes:
    print(n.pitches[0], n.offset, n.duration.quarterLength)
nuevo_midi.write('midi', 'hml.mid')

Note that I added a "show()" method, which starts up MuseScore (if you have it) to show you what the result looks like.  That's what made the original problem clear.

Hi Tim, thanks by your code I see your modifications are very important. I ran it but was the same result, there are no rests. I put two actualized captures to you see.

It worked for me.  Post your MIDI file and I'll take a look.

Hi Tim, How can I post a MIDI file?

Put it in a public server somewhere and post a link.  Do you have DropBox?  OneDrive?  Google Drive?  Box?

Here is the original file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p3bFgVsaDoqulYAS-8s5VKV-rFyIlUKh/view?usp=drivesdk

"Permission denied".
